# ICU - Order by case before character

Tags: c++, icu

Using `UCollator` from ICU in C++, I want to order by case before everything else.

Despite setting the below options, the actual characters are considered before case.

```
ucol_setAttribute(coll, UCOL_STRENGTH, UCOL_TERTIARY, &status);
ucol_setAttribute(coll, UCOL_CASE_FIRST, UCOL_LOWER_FIRST, &status);
ucol_setAttribute(coll, UCOL_CASE_LEVEL, UCOL_ON, &status);
```

The reason for this desired order is to replicate how C/C++ compares characters. An example being that `B < a` should be true, but `ucol_strcollIter` returns `1` (indicating `B > a`).

These are the results for some tests that I wrote, which should all pass:

```
A < a: FAIL
B < b: FAIL
a = a: PASS
B < a: FAIL
A < b: PASS
A < B: PASS
```

Any suggestion on how to configure `UCollator` to implement this would be much appreciated.

Comment: Why use UCollator for this?  Just use the ordering of the codepoints directly.  (Possibly converting to some normalized form first).

Comment: I am needing to use `UCollator` for this as I need the additional sorting functionality too (e.g. the handling of characters not used in the English language).

Comment: Sorting by codepoint will sort all Unicode characters.  Not just English ones.  (It may not give the order you want, but in that case you will need to explain what order you *do* want.)

Comment: Thanks - after looking back into the documentation to consider how to implement this (trying to replicate the comparison of characters in C/C++ with a mixture of UTF-8 and UTF-16 strings), I found that `Normalizer::compare` seems to work well for this.